# Combine bump texture normal with Dynamic Paint behaviour

Tags: shader-nodes, dynamic-paint

I am trying to combine two techniques from the following tutorials:

[Tutorial 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VHc1i9V3ZY): Using Dynamic Paint to make a plane behave like water (rippling as a boat object steers through it).

[Tutorial 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtlSIRh5r_E): Using a Musgrave texture as a Bump map applied to the normal input of a Principled BDSF node.

I'm using Evee.  When I apply the Bump Map from the Musgrave texture, all the behaviour of the Dynamic Paint effect on the plane disappears.

[image]

Is there some sort of mix shader I should be using to achieve this?

[image]

Blend file attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nDDwRMbqAv_1-bLOPnIAA5sUXy4J6B4D/view?usp=sharing) (with simplified geometry for the boat).

Comment: Hello, yes that's weird could you please share your file? (maybe replace the boat with a simpler object)

Comment: Done - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nDDwRMbqAv_1-bLOPnIAA5sUXy4J6B4D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it works for me except it's very discreet, I have to put the canvas' Scale Influence at 1 and the brush Factor at 2

Comment: Aaaa you are right! Many thanks - please add as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works except the wave is very discreet and you can't see it anymore because of the bump, put the canvas' *Scale Influence* at 1 and the brush *Factor* at 2